# Edit HTML string variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

```
var HTMLTest = `blablabla <h1 id="Title">Porsche 911 GT3 RS</h1> blablabla`
```

Ok so i got a huge HTML string which is a full HTML page with style and all and I want to edit the part with the id Title inside my string. How can I do it using only basic Javascript ? If it's possible

I tried to find and replace text directly in my string but the text will change at each iteration of my loop so I can't use this.

Comment: This should rather be done using a DOM parser than via string manipulation, to begin with.

Comment: That's what I understood but I am restricted by my intership's boss

Comment: _"but the text will change at each iteration of my loop "_ - what "loop"? This currently lacks context.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked for a duplicate that turned up [this classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  As an aside... If technical leadership is limiting the tools you can use, perhaps technical leadership has suggestions on how you can use the tools they allow?

Comment: I am in a SetInterval function to scan QRCodes, i need to put the data in my HTML string each iteration, which will change everytime

Comment: What *exactly* are your restrictions?   "basic Javascript" is too vague.  Do you consider regular expressions as "basic javascript"?  What about `new DOM Parser()` (as per provided answer) - is that "basic javascript"?  What about `.split()`?

Comment: Here's a *"basic javascript"* solution - but it has so many caveats that it's unusable outside your explicit scenario (specifically that you only have 1 `h1`), so not worth an answer by itself and there will be better solutions, depending on the restrictions:  `HTMLTest = HTMLTest.split('<h1 id="Title">')[0] + '<h1 id="Title">' + new_title + '</h1>' + HTMLTest.split("</h1>")[1];`

Comment: I've tried to use the DOM Parser anyway, sorry for your time guys. But i guess i'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
let htmlStr = `blablabla <h1 id="Title">Porsche 911 GT3 RS</h1> blablabla`;
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, "text/html");
doc.getElementById("Title").textContent = 'New title text';
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Okey well I've used this and converted it back to a String, sorry for the inconvenience/duplicate and thanks guys !